# MySQL Table 'users' already exists

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE weeki.users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    registration_id TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    api TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_At DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    disabled TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
    status VARCHAR(130) DEFAULT 'Just another user',
    icon TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX id (id)
)
```

MySQL #1050 - Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Delete table if exists before or create it only when not exists. How to do this? Please use search option as such questions were already asked

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION weeki.CreateGroup( GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT ) RETURNS INT(11) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN DECLARE groupID INT; INSERT INTO groups(NAME, icon, description) VALUES( GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription ); SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO group_members VALUES(groupID, GroupCreator); RETURN groupID; END; But what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in your case :

1. Delete your existing table
2. Create table

---

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `weeki.users`;
    CREATE TABLE weeki.users (
        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        registration_id TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        api TEXT NOT NULL,
        created_At DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        disabled TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
        status VARCHAR(130) DEFAULT 'Just another user',
        icon TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE INDEX id (id)
    )
```

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION weeki.CreateGroup(
    GroupName VARCHAR(50),
    GroupIcon TEXT,
    GroupDescription VARCHAR(130),
    GroupCreator INT
) RETURNS INT(11) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
    DECLARE
        groupID INT;
    INSERT INTO groups(NAME, icon, description)
VALUES(
    GroupName,
    GroupIcon,
    GroupDescription
);
SET
    groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO group_members
VALUES(groupID, GroupCreator); RETURN groupID;
    END;                                                                                              But what is the solution to this problem?